# Cucumber Java: Features File Mapping to Step Definitions

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

If i have 5 features file and 5 steps definitions. How cucumber know how to map the correct feature file to class? Besides, is there any problem running multiple features file with multiple step definitions class?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: StepDefinitons are kind off global in nature. As part off the initial process of running the runner all the stepdefinition methods in the glue folders are 'collected'. So it actually does not matter how many stepdef files or runner files u have.

Comment: I wonder how it map exactly the feature file to correct step definition class.

Comment: Using one step definition class per feature file is actually considered an [antipattern](https://docs.cucumber.io/guides/anti-patterns/). You should only define a step definition once; you can then reuse it in multiple feature files.

Answer (score 1):

@peterwkc - It doesn't map specific .feature file to specific class with steps definitions- rather it maps specific step from .feature file to corresponding annotation of steps definitions methods included in glue.

Answer (score 0):

1.How cucumber know how to map the correct feature file to class? 
A: In Runner file "features=''" will direct where to go and read the features. Once it reads the scenario it will look at glue in runner file "glue=''" that directs to all the step definitions. Then looks for the relevant snippet step that match to your scenario steps.

2. is there any problem running multiple features file with multiple step definitions class?
   A: All it looks for is unique snippet. It doesn't matter how many step definition classes you have for a feature file. However deriving too many step definitions for one feature file makes the framework complex, but if that suits your requirement then no problem.